# Coefficients of rational involution.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, rational-functions, mobius-transformation, involutions

Question:

(Spivak *Calculus* 3rd, Chapter 3, Problem 8)

For which numbers $a,b,c,d$ will the function

$$f(x) = \frac{ax + d}{cx + b}$$

satisfy $f(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$?

Attempt at an answer:

I tried to substitute $f(x)$ into itself, resulting in

$$f(f(x)) = \frac{a(\frac{ax + d}{cx + b}) + d}{c(\frac{ax + d}{cx + b}) + b} = \frac{(a^2 + cd)x + (a+b)d}{[(a+b)c]x+(b^2+cd)}$$

When this expression is set equal to $x$, I get an equation

$$[(a+b)c]x^2 + (b^2-a^2)x - (a+b)d = 0$$

Now, since this equation must hold for all $x$, I can select several arbitrary values, creating a system of as many equation as I want. This is where I am a little stuck; it seems that picking the correct values of $x$ is a matter of guessing and a little luck. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: No, you can't select arbitrary values. You can only choose any values of $a,b$ satisfying the further condition that $$(b-a)^2\ge -4cd,$$ so that $c$ and $d$ must always have different signs whenever they do not simultaneously vanish. Otherwise, you can only choose any values of $c,d$ satisfying the further condition that $b=-a.$ I assume, of course, that your function maps $\mathrm R$ into $\mathrm R.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations are fine and, no, you don't need guessing or luck. Note that$$(a+b)cx^2+(b^2-c^2)x-(a+b)d=(a+b)\bigl(cx^2+(b-a)x-d\bigr)$$and this will be the null polynomial if and only if one of these things occur:

- $a+b=0$;
- $c=b-a=d=0$.

So, there are two types of solutions to your problem:

- the functions of the type $\displaystyle x\mapsto\frac{ax+d}{cx-a}$;
- the functions of the type $\displaystyle x\mapsto\frac{ax}a=x$.

Of course, this last type consist only of the identity function.